# mongodb: How to delete specific key from a document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

This is my document :

```
{
    friends {
        "keyone" {
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        "keytwo" {
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        "keythree" {
            "foo" : "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update this document, to delete the **"keytwo"** array from my document.. so i want this result:

```
{
  friends {
       "keyone" {
          "foo" : "bar"
       },
       "keythree" {
           "foo" : "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?
I'm using jenssegers, A MongoDB based Eloquent model and Query builder for Laravel

Thanks for Advance!

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to stackoverflow! Are you using mongo shell or any particular language sdk?

Comment: i'm using jenssegers A MongoDB based Eloquent model and Query builder for Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove a particular key from a document.

`db.mycollection.update({}, {$unset: {"friends .keytwo":1}});`

If you want multiple documents to be updated, you can add `{multi: true}`:

`db.mycollection.update({}, {$unset: {"friends .keytwo":1}},{multi: true});`

Comment: i dont want to find, i want to update my specific document

Comment: aah, that changes the question completely!
I'll update my answer

Comment: can you tell me how to do that with jenssegers ? it's a MongoDB based Eloquent model and Query builder for Laravel

Comment: I've never used jenssegers. But just see how you can fire update command. `$unset` will be used in that